# Filter Django Generic Foreign Key by related model attribute

Tags: python, sql, django, oop, orm

I have  a model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag
```

How to filter a queryset by related object attribute? Not all of related objects have attribute 'name'

```
TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object__name='guido')
```

Comment: Not all of related objects have attribute 'name' that's mean they can be null?

Comment: @Bakhtiyar Bekbergen, no. Its mean that i have relations to different models(main  feature of generic foreign key), some of them had field 'name', some of them not.